# Can't receive data from type in procedure. Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 2 Types:

```
create or replace 
  type CASES_TYPE_N IS object(
    CASEID VARCHAR2(128),
    FirstNumber VARCHAR2(32),
    DLR number
  );

create or replace 
TYPE CASES_TABLE_N AS TABLE OF CASES_TYPE_N;
```

And Package with it's body:

```
create or replace 
PACKAGE BANKRUPT_TEST AS 
  procedure BANKRUPT_TEST_p(
                           pType            in integer,
                           pRequestDate         in varchar2,
                           CasesList_1      out CASES_TABLE_N,
                           ResultCode       out integer,
                           ErrorText        out varchar2);
END BANKRUPT_TEST;

create or replace
    PACKAGE BODY BANKRUPT_TEST AS
      procedure BANKRUPT_TEST_p(
                               pType              in integer,
                               pRequestDate     in varchar2,
                               CasesList_1          out CASES_TABLE_N,
                               ResultCode       out integer,
                               ErrorText        out varchar2) AS
      BEGIN 
        ResultCode := pType;
        ErrorText  := pRequestDate;

        select CASES_TYPE_N(CaseID,
                          FirstNumber,
                          dlr 
                     ) bulk collect
                  into CasesList_1
              from ( select
                        'CaseID' as CaseID,
                        'Fnum' as FirstNumber,
                        15 as dlr 
                      from dual
                  )
          ;
        NULL;
      END BANKRUPT_TEST_p;
    END BANKRUPT_TEST;
```

All of it was written and runs with Oracle SQL Developer.
As a result i receive only variables ResultCode and ErrorText. And I also should to have data from CasesList_1. But I don't. 
I don't receive any compilation errors. 
It have to work with types, not with cursors.
Could you help?

Comment: This should work. How do you call the procedure and check the result?

Comment: I just press RUN button. And set "IN" parameters:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your procedure with a small PLSQL block; for example the following runs your procedure and prints the result:

```
declare
    p1_in  integer := 10;
    p2_in  varchar2(10) := 'xxx';
    p1_out CASES_TABLE_N; 
    p2_out integer;
    p3_out varchar2(10);
begin      
    BANKRUPT_TEST.BANKRUPT_TEST_p(                        
                                     pType        => p1_in   ,
                                     pRequestDate => p2_in   ,
                                     CasesList_1  => p1_out  ,
                                     ResultCode   => p2_out  ,
                                     ErrorText    => p3_out  
                                 );
    if p1_out.count > 0 then
        for i in p1_out.first .. p1_out.last loop
            dbms_output.put_line(i || ' - ' ||
                                    p1_out(i).caseId  || ' - ' ||
                                    p1_out(i).firstNumber  || ' - ' ||
                                    p1_out(i).dlr
                                   );
        end loop;
    end if;
    dbms_output.put_line(p2_out);
    dbms_output.put_line(p3_out);
end;
```

the result:

```
1 - CaseID - Fnum - 15
10
xxx
```

If you run this in SQLPLUS, you should first give the `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` to enable printing.

If you run this in a different client, you have to check if the SERVEROUTPUT is enabled in you environment; the way is different from client to client.

Comment: You're welcome. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find something more on what to do when someone answers you.

Answer (score 0):

As the result this is working code.

```
create or replace 
     procedure BANKRUPT_TEST_p1(
                               pType              in integer,
                               in varchar2,
                           CasesList_1        out CASES_TABLE_N,
                           ResultCode       out integer,
                           ErrorText        out varchar2) IS
    nCur            number;

      BEGIN
       ResultCode := pType;
       ErrorText  := pRequestDate;

       begin
         CasesList_1:=CASES_TABLE_N();
         exception when others then null;
       end;

    for rec in(
        select distinct CaseID,
                        FirstNumber,
                        DLR
          from AA_TABLE
              where DownloadDate = pRequestDate and ClientID is not null
    ) loop
           CasesList_1.extend;
           nCur                           := CasesList_1.last;
           CasesList_1(nCur)              := CASES_TYPE_N(null, null, null);

           begin
              CasesList_1(nCur).CASEID := rec.caseid;
           exception when others then null;
           end;

           begin
              CasesList_1(nCur).FirstNumber := rec.firstnumber;
           exception when others then null;
           end;

           begin
              CasesList_1(nCur).DLR := rec.dlr;
           exception when others then null;
           end;
    end loop;
    NULL;
  END BANKRUPT_TEST_p1;
END BANKRUPT_TEST1;
```